# I can't except tweepy error

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

```
try:
    visitoruser = visitorapi.me()
    visitorapi.retweet(tweetid)
except tweepy.TweepError:
    dlacc = accounts.objects.get(twitterid=int(retweetmakers.twitterid))
    dlacc.delete()
```

TweepError at /retweet/
[{'message': 'Your account is suspended and is not permitted to access this feature.', 'code': 64}]

Why dont work tweepy.TweepError:

Comment: maybe because your account is suspended

Comment: okey i wanna detect and delete account.